# filter values using this code "Filter(function(x) condition on x , Var )" but using condition based on values calculated value of var

Tags: r

Apologies, if this is a simple question. I'm trying to use "Filter(function(x) condition with x , Var )" to filter values in a variable. The only thing is I want to be able to use a manipulation of "x" in the condition. Here below is a simplistic example. In the below code, I want to filter values in variable that are greater than the mean of that variable.

```
Var1 = 1:10
Filter(function(x) x > mean(x) , Var1 )
> integer(0)
```

As you can see it doesn't work the way expected. There are other ways to filter but I'd like to do it in this format. Is there a way to write the "mean(x)" within the function part to make this work? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` is a single value as it is looped over each element of the `vector` so `mean(x)` is just x.  Instead it would be `mean(Var1)`.

```
Filter(function(x) x > mean(Var1), Var1 )
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

If we want to understand what the 'x' is, just use a `print` statement

```
Filter(function(x) print(x), Var1)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

This can be reused by wrapping in a function

```
f1 <- function(vec) {
      Filter(function(x) x > mean(vec), vec)
 }
f1(Var1)
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

Or use `subset`

```
subset(Var1, Var1 > mean(Var1))
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```